# MA Theses on the Minimalist Program

Tags: syntax

Could someone provide me with a master's thesis on the minimalist program? I couldn't find them on the net. I am working on my master's thesis, and I need a model for it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually the university keeps old theses and these are often available to all. It’s probably more important that you use one from the same university than one in the same theoretical framework

Comment: @Lambie the minimalist program is the latest framework within Chomsky's generative grammar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalist_program

Comment: To find Master's theses, you have to go to university libraries and look them up. Most are not just hanging around on the internet.

Comment: Don't you have an advisor? You should ask your advisor about structuring your masters thesis.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone can, but we could explain how you might find one, using internet sources. First, you need a list of universities that have MA programs in linguistics, then you need to limit the search to programs that require a thesis. You then search department web-pages and university libraries using appropriate keywords, to get a list of plausible titles. You could use specific jargon like "merge" and "checking" in order to filter out descriptive theses, Cat-grammar theses, HPSG, and so on; or, find a supervisor known to operate under Minimalism and see what theses are available. There is probably about a 50-50 chance that the work will be available online somewhere.